# Cómo puedo ejecutar evento en MySQL todos los días a las 3 am

Tags: mysql, eventos

Me gustaría saber, si es posible ejecutar un evento en `MySQL`.

Quiero respaldar registros del día anterior. Debería ser ejecutado todos los días a las `3 am`.

El script siguiente ejecuta cada 3 horas, pero por la magnitud de registros, lo ideal es que se ejecute solo a las 3 am:

```
CREATE EVENT `Backup`  ON SCHEDULE EVERY '3' HOUR 
STARTS '2017-12-12 00:00:00'  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
INSERT INTO MiTabla_B SELECT * FROM MiTabla_A WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(fecha, '%Y%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: Esto podrías hacerlo desde un cron pero es directo en el servidor no en el mysql

Comment: ¿Y cual es el problema con el script en tu pregunta?

Comment: Que se ejecuta cada 3 horas, y por la magnitud de registros, lo ideal es que se ejecute solo a las 3  am

Comment: Algún ejemplo de agregar el evento en cron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En vez de:

```
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '3' HOUR 
STARTS '2017-12-12 00:00:00'
```

... que como tu mismo comentas ejecuta el evento a cada 3 horas, crea el evento para que comienze a ejecutar a las `3 am`, y que siga repitiendo la ejecución a cada día:

```
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS '2017-12-12 03:00:00'
```