# Crear una columna en una tabla basada en datos almacenados en otra tabla

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, cron, etl

Tengo dos bases de datos, una de mis contactos y otra de sus pedidos vinculados por su contact_id. Me gustaría crear una nueva columna `orders.exclude_from_statistics` en esta última cuando el donante es `Great Benefactor` o que el campo `caimpaing` es `nuit`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `Contact ID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Great Benefactor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`id`, `user_id`, `Great Benefactor`) VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '0'),
  ('3', '0'),
  ('4', '0');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `Order ID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Amount` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Contact ID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Campaign` VARCHAR(255)
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `Amount`, `contact_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '100',1, NULL),
  ('2', '20', 2, NULL),
  ('3', '10', 3, `nuit`),
  ('4', '30', 1, NULL);
```

Pensé hacer:

```
SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN contacts.`Great Benefactor` ON concats.`Contact ID` = orders.`Contact ID`;
```

Pero no crea una nueva tabla. Probablemente necesite un ALTER TABLE:

```
UPDATE orders
        INNER JOIN contacts ON orders.id = contacts.`Contact ID`
        IF contacts.`Great Benefactor` = true OR orders.Campaign = `nuit` 
            SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 1
        ELSE 
            SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 0
        ;
```

No soy seguro de ALTER TABLE pensaba tambien en UPDATE.

El contexto es hacer esto cada noche en mi ETL:

`crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics.py`

```
from etl.utils.logging import info
from etl.mysql.connect import db

def add_column_exclude_from_statistics():
    with db as c:
        # Create new columns where exclude_from_statistics
        info("Creating column exclude from statistics")
        c.execute("""
            UPDATE orders
            INNER JOIN contacts ON orders.id = contacts.`Contact ID`
            IF contacts.`Great Benefactor` = true OR orders.Campaign = `nuit` 
                SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 1
            ELSE 
                SET orders.exclude_from_statistics = 0
            ;
        """)

def main():
    info("Table crm.orders")
    add_column_exclude_from_statistics()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Que ejecuto cada noche desde main.py

```
import ...

def main():

    crm_orders_exclude_from_statistics.main()

    info('End ETL main process')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Como dices, si quieres actualizar una tabla debes hacer un ALTER TABLE, porque el SELECT lo que hace es devolver los resultados que cumplan tu condición.

Comment: Muchas gracias @SergioGarridoDomínguez , añadiré lo que esto me lleva a pensar.

Comment: Eso de crear columnas en una tabla de forma "dinámica" suena muy raro. ¿Es eso lo que quieres, crear una columna cuando se dé una determinada condición? Si es eso, ¿hay algo que lo justifique realmente?

Comment: Esto es para un ETL, @A.Cedano

Comment: Sumado a lo que mencionan los colegas, desde la versión 5.1 de MySql esta la opción de crear eventos los cuales se ejecutan cuando uno lo determine.

Comment: No lo entiendo bien, @RobertoPaillao ¿Puedes explicármelo como si tuviera 12 años?

Comment: Me refiero a que es innecesario crear una rutina en python y tomarse el trabajo de configurar dicha tarea para ejecutarla periódicamente, cuando MySql ya puede hacer eso. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124304/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-ejecutar-evento-en-mysql-todos-los-d%C3%ADas-a-las-3-am